# Exponential generating function with factorial.

Tags: combinatorics

Can't solve this example:

$$a_{n+1} = 2(n+1)a_n+(n+1)!$$

$$\sum \frac{a_{n+1}z^{n+1}}{(n+1)!} = \sum \frac{2(n+1)a_n z^{n+1}}{(n+1)!} + \sum \frac{(n+1)! z^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$$

$$F(z)- a_0 = 2zF(z) + ...???...$$

I just don't guess how I can transform last term
($\sum (n+1)!(z^{n+1})/(n+1)!$) according list of generating functions. If you know how I can do it-tell me please!)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Thank you for information!

Comment: Welcome to MSE ^_^. I've edited your question to use mathjax, but as other commenters have noted, you should do this yourself going forwards

Comment: appreciated to you for it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've noticed, if we write

$$F(z) \triangleq \sum \frac{a_n}{n!}z^n$$

for the exponential generating function of $a_n$, then the recurrence becomes:

$$F(z) - a_0 = 2z F(z) + \sum \frac{(n+1)!}{(n+1)!} z^{n+1}$$

Of course, we can cancel the $(n+1)!$ terms to see

$$F(z) - a_0 = 2z F(z) + \sum z^{n+1}$$

It is at this point that one should recall $\frac{1}{1-z} = \sum z^n$, and so

$$F(z) - a_0 = 2z F(z) + \frac{z}{1-z}$$

Do you see how to finish it from here?

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: It was so easy, sorry me:/ Thank you for your explanation, you very helped me!

Comment: Happy to help ^_^